# Socket programming in language interoperability

Tags: sockets, programming-languages, interop, language-interoperability

I was wondering whether different (high/mid level) languages (c/c++/java/c#) supporting basic networking features like sockets, can work/communicate together on different platforms?

Are there any existing projects (open or otherwise) to make it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. TCP/IP sockets are language independent standard. For example, you can open a socket in Java client it can connect to a listening server written in C++ or any other language. AJAX is another example.

Comment: Homework question... lol.

Comment: As far as I know sockets are mainly used for data transmissions..what I meant by interoperability was "language Independency" where an environment could be created similar to a CLR..through which languages could call each other/operate on each others objects... I do know their is JNI and Language independent RMI (JRMI) provided by java.(CORBA) etc they expose certain traits of the language...

Comment: That's not the question you asked. This is an answer to the question you asked. If you want a different answer you need to ask a different question, and you need to do so *in your question,* not down here in the comments to an answer.

Comment: You are referencing completely different things here: CLR is completely different than RMI/Corba, which is completely different than JNI. You could use sockets to do something similar to RMI and Corba, but you would be doing it at a much lower level. Basically you would lose the serialization that they do. And Sockets wouldn't be the most efficient way if you just want to do interprocess communication.